# Prove that the $L^1$-derivative of $f\ast \varphi$ is $f\ast \varphi'$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Prove that the $L^1$-derivative of  $f\ast \varphi$   is $f\ast
>  \varphi'$.

My Attempt:
Note that there is a notion of derivative:  $h\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ is the $L^1$-derivative of $f$ if

$$
\lim_{y \rightarrow 0}  \frac{\tau_y f -f}{y} =h 
$$

where, $\tau_y f(x)=f(x+y)$ is the *shift operator*, and the limit is meant with respect to the $L^1$-norm.

We also know that
$$f \ast \phi= \phi \ast f=\int_\mathbb{R}{\phi(x-t)f(t)dt}$$
Note that in our case the convolution is defined everywhere since $\phi$ is compactly supported and thus bounded, and $f \in L^1$.

I am really having trouble getting any further on this problem because my class really sped through this section. I was hoping someone could help me out. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume $\varphi\in C^\infty_0$ we have $f*\varphi,f*\varphi'\in C^{\infty}$ and we may replace the $L^1$-derivative with the classical derivative. The problem boils down to showing that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(f*\varphi)(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi(x-t)f(t)\,dt \color{red}{=} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi'(x-t)f(t)\,dt = (f*\varphi')(x) $$
holds, which is [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). On the other hand $C^{\infty}_0$ is dense (with respect to the uniform norm) in the space of compact-supported, differentiable functions, so we may conclude by density. As an alternative, we may simply write down

$$ \lim_{y\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\frac{1}{y}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(x+y-t)f(t)\,dt - f(x)\right]-\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi'(x-t)f(t)\,dt\right|\,dx\stackrel{?}{=}0$$
invoke Lebesgue differentiation theorem and perform a bunch of algebraic manipulations, essentially analogous to the previous ones. The principle is that a $f\in L^1$ is not necessarily pointwise-defined, but $f\in L^1$ implies that 
$f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)\,dt $ (the RHS is also known as the *Lebesgue value* of $f$ at $x$) holds almost everywhere, so if some $f\in L^1$ appears under the integral sign, it can be considered as the function associating to $x$ the value $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2h}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(t)\,dt = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\left(f*\frac{\mathbb{1}_{(-h,h)}}{2h}\right)(x)$. But if $f$ is a primitive of its $L^1$-derivative, the identity above just follows from integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help.